# Overriding a method used in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this [watermark](https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-Watermark) jquery plugin, but it has issue with hidden elements, so I found this [actual](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual) jquery plugin to fix the issue.

The simple fix is to edit the watermark plugin (on line 92):

```
e_height = $elem.outerHeight();
```

to

```
e_height = $elem.actual('outerHeight');
```

...but that would couple the two plugins together...I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

In another js file, I'm trying override the outerHeight function in the watermark plugin.

Here's what I've tried (without success) so far (2nd attempt using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644713/101022)):

```
// 1st attempt    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.watermark.outerHeight = $(this).actual('outerHeight');
});

// 2nd attempt
(function($){
    var _old = $.fn.watermark.outerHeight;

    $.fn.watermark.outerHeight = function(){
        return _old.call(actual,'outerHeight');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Feels like chicken/egg...both outerHeight and actual are applied to an element:

```
$('.thing').outerHeight();
$('.thing').actual('outerHeight');
```

...so how do I replace outerHeight() with actual('outerHeight') in the watermark plugin and have actual('outerHeight') act on $('.thing')...or $elem, in the watermark plugin?

Comment: Since `actual()` calls `outerHeight()` internally, I don't think what you want can be achieved. Modifying the watermark plugin might be your best choice here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can I not create a locally scoped outerHeight method in watermark plugin that uses the actual plugin?

Comment: Just realized it's recursive...despite the scoping.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You cannot create a locally scoped `outerHeight()` method around the watermark plugin because it calls `$.fn.outerHeight()`, and you can only override that, however temporarily, either globally or not at all. In other words, all callers will be impacted for the duration of your override, including `actual()` itself.